# How do I get preg_replace to replace double braced delimiters in html using file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am able to get the preg_replace function to find and replace only the inner braced delimiter. eg: the script below replaces `{ FIELD: date }` with `"12/12/2015"` but leaves the outer braces.

I tried escaping the outer braces to no avail. Help please!

```
$myFileToCopy = file_get_contents("http://localhost/templatemaker/masterTemplates/".$object['fileName'].$object['fileExtension']);


$myFileToCopy =  preg_replace("{{ FIELD: date }}", "12/12/2015", $myFileToCopy);
```

Comment: The designer chose this as his match strings in template html files.  No error tho, it just replaces the inner braced content.  It doesnt error it replaces  {12/12/2015} int the html where it found {{ FIELD: date }}... escaping the outer braces didnt work...

Comment: yeah ill try that. :) was up to late coding i think. Hopeful str_replace replaces all instances else Ill use a regex.

Comment: str_replace worked perfectly thanks Chris85

Comment: No problem, please see answer below for more details and if it resolves your issue be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't in need of a regex here given your example so `str_replace`, http://php.net/str_replace, should suffice.

```
$myFileToCopy = file_get_contents("http://localhost/templatemaker/masterTemplates/".$object['fileName'].$object['fileExtension']);
$myFileToCopy = str_replace("{{ FIELD: date }}", "12/12/2015", $myFileToCopy);
```

If you wanted to do it with a regex you could try,

```
$myFileToCopy = file_get_contents("http://localhost/templatemaker/masterTemplates/".$object['fileName'].$object['fileExtension']);
$myFileToCopy =  preg_replace("~\{\{ FIELD: date \}\}~", "12/12/2015", $myFileToCopy);
```

Note the `~`, these are delimiters, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php, which lets PHP know where the expression starts and ends.